# getting syntax error in property.setProperty("mail.smtp.host",host);

Tags: java, selenium, smtp

I am getting the syntax for the below line while trying to send the mail through SMTP .I tried in google but didnt get any relevant answer.

**property.setProperty("mail.smtp.host",host);**

**CODE:**

```
public class SendMail {

//Recipient Mail id 
String to = "Receiver Mail ID";
//Sender Mail Id
String from = "Sender Mail ID";
//Sending email from the localhost
String host = "localhost";
//Get System Properties
Properties property = System.getProperties();
//Setup the mail server
property.setProperty("mail.smtp.host",host);
property.setProperty("mail.smtp.port" , "465");
//property.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
//Get the default session object
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(property);


try
{
    //Create a default MimeMessage object.
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    //Set From: header field of the header
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    //Set To : header field of the header
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

    //Set Subject : header field
    message.setSubject("Automation Testing Report");

    //Create the Message part
    BodyPart messageBodypart = new MimeBodyPart();

    //Enter the message in the Mail Body
    messageBodypart.setText("***********Find the below for the Report****************");

    //Create a Multipart Message
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    //Set Text message part
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodypart);


    //Part two is attachment
    /*create the Message part*/
    messageBodypart = new MimeBodyPart();
    String filename = "E:\\Project\\jar\\Selenium        Scripts\\Hybrid_Driven\\test-output\\emailable-report.html";
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodypart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodypart.setFileName(filename);
    //set the text message part
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodypart);

    //Send the complete message part
    message.setContent(multipart);


    //Send message 
    Transport.send(message);
    System.out.println("Mail has sent successfully");

}

catch(MessagingException mex)
{
    mex.printStackTrace();
}

}

}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put java code directly into a class. It needs to be within methods. The following is happily accepted by the compiler:

```
public class SendMail {

  ...

  //Get System Properties
  java.util.Properties property = System.getProperties();

  void doSomething()
  {
    property.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    property.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    ...

  }
}
```

Comment: Ya super it got fixed. But what is the reason.we shouldn't mention it in the class definition?

Comment: Class definitions are just not meant for executing code in java. This seems different in other languages, e.g. scala. But the code in the class definition in scala is implicitly just part of the default constructor. Basically, the class definition defines which member fields and methods a class has. Constructors and methods can then work with these fields and methods

Comment: Thank You for the clarification .One more thing by executing this class i am not getting email as a output.i don't know whether it is executing or not .How to find that.I am using POM Model